# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a blog Using PDO, the problem is when I go to the index file that is supposed to list my articles, I get this error.

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message ' in C:\wamp\www\simpleblog\includes\config.php

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\wamp\www\simpleblog\includes\config.php on line 11

I am very new to PDO, so i can't figure out what could be causing the problem. I have looked at other problems but I couldn't find anything similar to this. I have checked phpmyadmin and the database name is correct.
Here is my index.php

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <h1>Blog</h1>
        <hr />

        <?php
            try {

                $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                    echo '<div>';
                        echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                        echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
                        echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
                    echo '</div>';

                }

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

And my config.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','blog');

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=80;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//load classes as needed
function __autoload($class) {

   $class = strtolower($class);

    //if call from within assets adjust the path
   $classpath = 'classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
    }   

    //if call from within admin adjust the path
   $classpath = '../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
    }

    //if call from within admin adjust the path
   $classpath = '../../classes/class.'.$class . '.php';
   if ( file_exists($classpath)) {
      require_once $classpath;
    }       

}

$user = new User($db); 
?>
```

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: what could be the problem ? Line 11 on config.php is $db = new PDO(***** so I thought there is something wrong with my PDO declaration.

Comment: it is clearly described in the error message.

Comment: Your server is poorly configured.

Comment: I reckon the port you've provided to the PDO connection is wrong. Port 80 is usually default port for the web server. 3306, on the other hand, is the default one for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try changing the port no

Comment: Yes, he did. `config.php`, the definition of the connection - `;port=80;`

Comment: I removed the port no to set it to default and it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: For future reference, check in `cmd` which ports are used by `netstat -aon`, that'll list the ports which processes are attached to